# Checking a table for an existing record before a new record is inserted

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, detailsview

I have a details view that I am using to fill a table with values.  It is now inserting values correctly but I needed to now check to see if the user is trying to enter a new record that would interfere with the previous records.

If A user enters a new event that falls on 2012-12-12 but that same user has already entered a record for 2012-12-12 then i would like an error to be thrown and the record not able to be inserted.

Just checking for a unique record of the time wont work because a different user can create an even 2012-12-12 and it will be acceptable. Only the same user cannot create the same events dates.  So I know I need to check two of the fields in the table but I was unsure of how to do this checking in my code.

For example:

user 1 new event 2012-12-12 ----- ok

user 2 new event 2012-12-12 ----- ok

user 3 new event 2012-12-12 ----- ok

user 2 new event 2012-12-12 ----- should throw an error and not allow that record to be created.

user 3 new event 2012-10-12 ----- ok

**EDITED**

Currently I am using this to update the table:

```
   public void UpdateForm(Int64 requestid,
                              Decimal empid,
                              String leave,
                              DateTime startdate,
                              DateTime enddate,
                              String starttime,
                              String endtime,
                              String standby,
                              String status,
                              String rsn,
                              String remarks,
                              String approver,
                              String with,
                              String reqleave,
                              String FIRSTNAME,
                              String LASTNAME)
    {

        var CurrUser = "a03       ";

        Account.Login uusr = new Account.Login();
        CurrUser = uusr.User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToUpper();

        var sql = "update TIME.request set empid=@empid, leave=@leave, with=@with, startdate=@startdate, reqleave=@reqleave, enddate=@enddate, starttime=@starttime, endtime=@endtime, standby=@standby, status=@status, rsn=@rsn, remarks=@remarks, approver=@approver where requestid = @requestid";

        using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.DeriveParameters();
                cmd.Parameters["@requestid"].Value = requestid;
                cmd.Parameters["@empid"].Value = empid;
                cmd.Parameters["@leave"].Value = leave;
                cmd.Parameters["@startdate"].Value = startdate;
                cmd.Parameters["@enddate"].Value = enddate;
                cmd.Parameters["@starttime"].Value = starttime;
                cmd.Parameters["@endtime"].Value = endtime;
                cmd.Parameters["@standby"].Value = standby;
                cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value = status;
                cmd.Parameters["@rsn"].Value = rsn;
                cmd.Parameters["@remarks"].Value = remarks;
                cmd.Parameters["@approver"].Value = approver;
                cmd.Parameters["@reqleave"].Value = reqleave;
                cmd.Parameters["@with"].Value = with;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look up `Constraint` for your particular RDBMS. A constraint allows you to prevent duplicate records (or duplicates based on a subset of the fields) from being inserted into a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stored procedure and have an output parameter, check if the item your inserting exists:

```
if exists(select 1 from table where user = @user and eventtime = @eventtime)
  begin
    set @output = 'event already exists'
  end 
else
 begin
    --Prevent DBNull output, see comments
    set @output = ''
   --Insert into table
 end
```

Add an output parameter to the procedure through C#

```
  var output = new SqlParameter() { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, ParameterName = "@Output" };
  var cmd = new SqlCommand("procname", connection)
  cmd.Parameters.Add(output);
  //Add other params
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output.Value))
    //Handle the error
    throw new Exception("Already exists");
```

A stored procedure in SQL is what you are looking for with the relevant parameters following the above, comment if there is something you don't understand.

EDIT: How to create and call a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prefix_SomeProcName]

--Parameters you need from the front end
@User varchar(50),
@EventTime datetime,
@Output varchar(100) output

--Created by: Your name
--Created date: Todays date
--Description: To do some stuff

AS

--Do your stuff here
if exists(select 1 from table where user = @user and eventtime = @eventtime)
  begin
    set @output = 'event already exists'
  end 
else
 begin
    --Prevent DBNull output, see comments
    set @output = ''
   --Insert into table
 end
```

Then you need a to import `System.Data.SqlClient` and do the following.

```
using(SqlConnection con = New SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Prefix_SomeProcName", con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   var output = new SqlParameter() { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, ParameterName = "@Output" };
   //Add your other parameters
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DatatTable dt = New DataTable();
   sda.Fill(dt);
}
```

The `DataTable` will now have the contents of the procedure if there is a select statement in it. Also, after the `Fill()` command you can access output.Value as mentioned in the above code.

Comment: If the INSERT is executed would the value of `SqlParameter output` be `DBNull`?  If so, wouldn't `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` throw an exception?  If I'm right about this, maybe the solution is to set a string value in both SQL if statement branches.

Comment: @pseudocoder Your correct it would return DBNull, you would either do what you have suggested or change the check for `IsNullOrEmpty` too check for `output.Value != DBNull.Value'

Comment: Im mostly unsure as to where i need to place the stored procedure and where i need to call the procedure in the code. I have been searching stored procedures and there is never a real description on what method i need to place it in. I get errors when I try to put it on my sql statement.

Comment: @user1596472 There are plenty of examples out there for stored procedures if you don't know about them - all it takes is a bit of research and the first link you come across will help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx. Anyway, I have tried to give you a simple explanation on how to create and call a procedure, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

create a unique Constraint on the columns

[Click here for examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint name> UNIQUE (user,date)
```

**Edit:**

as per your comment, please try this:

```
ALTER TABLE TIME.request
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_request UNIQUE (empid, startdate, enddate)
```

Comment: I couldn't get my constraints to run with unique. I have tried these select statements: select * from TIME.request add constraint empid unique(startdate, enddate) where empid = aa073
---
select * from TIME.request where emppid = aa073 add constraint empid unique(startdate, enddate)
---
SELECT unique(empid, startdate, enddate) FROM TIME.request ORDER BY startdate

Comment: You cannot use it with the select statement

Comment: ALTER TABLE TIME.request
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_request UNIQUE (empid, startdate, enddate)

Comment: the above statement you have to run in sql server query window.. then the table will allow only unique values for the values empid, startdate, enddate (together)

Comment: It still will not execute, it gave me this error -----One of the following has occurred: -- An object created in a CREATE SCHEMA statement is qualified by a name other than the schema name. All objects created in a CREATE SCHEMA statement must be either qualified by the schema name TIME or not qualified. Unqualified objects are implicitly qualified by the schema name. -- A constraint name was qualified by a name that is not the same as the qualifier for the table.  A constraint for a table must be qualified by the same schema as the table.

Comment: Im using iseries... IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries

Answer (score 0):

If this behaviour is epxected and you don't want the overhead of trapping the exception, you can check for existence in the same action as the isnert:

insert into myTable(...)

```
select ...
where not exists (select 1 from myTable where....)
```

This will work in Sql Server, but not with MySql.

Comment: @pseudocoder: hence my comment that is for situations where it is not an "exceptional" that the rows are already there: for instance when performing bulk imports